# Convergent Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the sequence $\{$cos$(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n})\}_{n=1}^\infty$ convergent?

I guess it is divergent because cos function is oscillating. But not sure. I am stuck in doing justification too. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at $\cos \left(\pi n + \pi(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n)\right)$.

Comment: Ok this equals cos$(n\pi)$cos$(\pi(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n))=(-1)^n$cos$(\pi(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n))$. So by alternating series test the given sequence converges to $0$. Am I correct?

Comment: Form an approximation of the cos, you'll get an alternating series and an absolutely converging series ( + o() of the latter) and you will be able to use the alternating series test

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What is 
$$\lim_n \sqrt{n^2+n}- (n+ \frac{1}{2})$$